# Configure JPA Attribute Converter to Use LONGTEXT Instead of VARCHAR

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA attribute converters to map a custom data type to a database column. The attribute converter I've implemented serializes my custom type to JSON and stores it as a VARCHAR column in the database. However, I need the column to be of type a large character-data type, and I'd like to achieve this without writing RDBMS-specific column definitions.

Here's the current implementation of my attribute converter:

```
@Converter
public class GenericDataConvertor implements AttributeConverter<Object, String> {
    // ... (converter methods)
}
```

The issue is that the generated column in the database is of type VARCHAR, and I want it to be of type a large character-data type. I'm aware that I can achieve this by providing RDBMS-specific column definitions, but I'm looking for a more database-agnostic solution that would work across different database systems without modifying the column definition for each.

Convertor is used

```
    @Convert(converter = GenericDataConvertor.class)
    @Lob
    Object value;
```

When I use @Lob, type of column becomes oid in Postgresql. But I want to it to be text type.
If I remove @Lob, column type becomes varchar.

**My Questions:**

1. Is there a way to configure JPA or the attribute converter to generate a a large character-data type column instead of a VARCHAR column without writing RDBMS-specific column definitions?
2. Are there any annotations, configurations, or settings that I can use to influence the generated column type in a more database-agnostic manner?
3. If such an approach is not available, what would be the recommended way to handle this requirement while maintaining database portability?

I appreciate any advice or guidance on how to achieve this modification to the column type without resorting to specifying RDBMS-specific column definitions. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: This is a hibernate issue where they switched behavior in https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/discussions/4361 to use OID instead of text on Postgres. You might try writing your own custom dialect to override that behavior change, or have it use TEXT without the Lob designation. Otherwise, there is no DB agnostic way to specify Text column type should be used within your entity - though you could define DB specific orm.xml files

Comment: As per https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14211 , you can use the @Type(type = ”text”) annotation, but I don't know how DB agnostic that is.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing because you first mention the type `LONGTEXT` which is specific to MySQL/MariaDB, and you then ask for a database-agnostic solution.

Assuming you want for a large character-data type to be used (`LONGTEXT`, `CLOB`, `TEXT` etc.), isn't `@Lob private String longTextAttribute;` what you want?

Comment: I updated the question to clarify. @Lob generates oid type column in postgresql